# Does dropbear take care of hosts.allow and hosts.deny?

Tags: ssh, ip, hosts, denyhosts, dropbear

I'm running `dropbear` as SSH daemon on Debian (actually Raspbian). I tried setting

```
# /etc/hosts.allow
dropbear:192.168.1.1
# my static ip from which I SSH connect to the device
```

and

```
# /etc/hosts.deny
ALL:ALL
# block all others
```

Then I restarted the whole device. I could still SSH into the device from different IP addresses and even from remote. Did I configure the files wrong or does `dropbear` not support these two files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbear doesn't include any support for `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny`. These files are managed by the [TCP wrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Wrapper) library (`libwrap`), which Dropbear doesn't use. Some third-party packages patch Dropbear for TCP wrapper support, but not Debian.

You can start Dropbear via [`tcpd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpd) to get TCP wrapper support.

```
/usr/sbin/tcpd /usr/sbin/dropbear -i
```

If you only want to filter by IP address, you can do it with iptables.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# /etc/hosts.deny
sshd:ALL:spawn /bin/echo  the ip %h tried to access `/bin/date`>> /var/log/ssh.log
```

and

```
# /etc/hosts.allow
sshd:192.168.1.1
```

if does not work try again with dropbear this way.

```
# /etc/hosts.deny
dropear:ALL:spawn /bin/echo  the ip %h tried to access `/bin/date`>> /var/log/ssh.log
```

and

```
# /etc/hosts.allow
dropbear:192.168.1.1
```

and check if dropbear have support for tcp/wrappers.

```
ldd /path/to/dropbear
```

look for **libwrap.so.0 →  /lib/libwrap.so.0**

Comment: Dropbear doesn't come with support TCP wrappers, and Debian doesn't add it either.